# Postgres: pass row value to select subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, subquery

The problem is to get the percent of result for each day where `status = '404 NOT FOUND'`

```
SELECT CAST(time AS DATE) as day, status, count(*),
        count(*) * 100.0 / (
            SELECT count(*) FROM log
            GROUP BY CAST(time AS DATE)
            HAVING CAST(time AS DATE) = '2016-07-17'
        ) as percent 
FROM log L
GROUP BY day, status
HAVING status = '404 NOT FOUND'
ORDER BY percent DESC
```

**Query Result**

```
day          | status          | count  | percent
---------------------------------------------------------------
2016-07-17   | 404 NOT FOUND   | 1267   | 2.2650481792016018
2016-07-24   | 404 NOT FOUND   | 429    | 0.76693422957970574039
2016-07-05   | 404 NOT FOUND   | 425    | 0.75978332767220265656
2016-07-19   | 404 NOT FOUND   | 422    | 0.75442015124157534369
2016-07-21   | 404 NOT FOUND   | 419    | 0.74905697481094803082
2016-07-08   | 404 NOT FOUND   | 416    | 0.74369379838032071795
2016-07-06   | 404 NOT FOUND   | 414    | 0.74011834742656917604
2016-07-09   | 404 NOT FOUND   | 410    | 0.73296744551906609221
```

Instead of having `2016-07-17` hardcoded, I'd like to pass the value of `day` in the outer query i.e `L.day`

Like so:

```
SELECT CAST(time AS DATE) as day, status, count(*),
        count(*) * 100.0 / (
            SELECT count(*)FROM log
            GROUP BY CAST(time AS DATE)
            HAVING CAST(time AS DATE) = L.day
        ) as percent 
FROM log L
GROUP BY day, status
HAVING status = '404 NOT FOUND'
ORDER BY percent DESC
```

**This gives**

```
ERROR:  column l.day does not exist
LINE 5:    HAVING CAST(time AS DATE) = L.day
                                       ^
```

**UPDATES: based on comments**

```
SELECT CAST(time AS DATE) as day, status, count(*),
        count(*) * 100.0 / (
            SELECT count(*) FROM log
            WHERE CAST(time AS DATE) = '2016-07-17'
        ) as percent 
FROM log L
GROUP BY day, status
HAVING status = '404 NOT FOUND'
ORDER BY percent DESC
```

Same result.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access an alias on the same level where it's defined, you need to use `= cast(l.time as date)`.

But that having clause doesn't really make sense - at least to me

I think what you want is:

```
SELECT CAST(time AS DATE) as day, 
       status, 
       count(*),
       count(*) * 100.0 / (SELECT count(*)
                           FROM log l2
                           where cast(l2.time as date) = CAST(l.time AS DATE)) as percent 
FROM log L
GROUP BY day, status
HAVING status = '404 NOT FOUND'
ORDER BY percent DESC;
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/SYJV63284

Comment: Right! `GROUP/HAVING` is not needed in the subquery (Tunnel vision ) However, I cannot use `l.time` in the subquery because it is not part of the outer `GROUP BY`

Comment: I see. But I'm getting `ERROR:  subquery uses ungrouped column "l.time" from outer query`.
Could this be an issue with my Postgres version or client? (Postico)

Comment: @JoshuaAzemoh: Probably a version thing. There was a change in the `group by` behaviour in 9.6

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll look that up.